# i cant declaring in query

Tags: mysql, sql, case, declare

```
@a =( CASE WHEN amount IS NOT NULL THEN amount1 
      WHEN percentage IS NOT NULL THEN sco.amount *  1 + (percentage / 100) END) AS data1
```

without @a i am getting result but with @a i am not getting result

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i want to add two case last that is why i am declaring variable mysq

Comment: *without @a i am getting result but with @a i am not getting result* What do you want to achieve? Now you compare the value of `@a` variable with the `CASE` result. If you want to assign the value to the variable then you must use assigning operator `:=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this below , you were missing :

```
@a :=( CASE WHEN amount IS NOT NULL THEN amount1 
          WHEN percentage IS NOT NULL THEN sco.amount *  1 + (percentage / 100) END) AS data1
```